# Taking int input and parsing into char

Tags: java, string, char, int

So my main got deleted 2 days ago and my teacher helped me a bit with the `switch` code. I rebuilt the code yesterday and he was away yesterday and could not help me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter your birthYear");
            birthYear = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            int length = String.valueOf(birthYear).length();
            System.out.println(length);
            if (length != 4) {
                lengthTest = false;
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
            } else {
                lengthTest = true;

            }
            test = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
        }

    } while (test == true ^ lengthTest != false);
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-4 \n"
                + "1 = AreaOfTriangle \n" + 
                "----------------------------------\n" + 
                "2 = HoursToDaysAndHours Calculator \n" + 
                "---------------------------------- \n" + 
                "3 = CelciusToFahrenheit Calculator \n" + 
                "----------------------------------\n" + 
                "4 = BirthdayGame \r\n" + 
                "----------------------------------");



        try {
            choice = Integer.toString(input.nextInt()).charAt(0);
            System.out.println(choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            aOT.areaOfTriangle();
            break;
        case 2:
            hTDAH.hoursToDaysAndHours();
            break;
        case 3:
            cTF.celciusToFahrenheit();
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Code not implemented");
            break;
        case 'e':
            repeat = false;
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("");
                break;
        } 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Awnser");
        }

    } while (repeat == true);

}
```

My problem is in my switch case i want to be able to use int's and Char's at the same time. For example i want to use e to exit and and the 4 numbers

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `while (repeat == true)` is the same as `while (repeat)` and `while (test == true ^ lengthTest != false)` is the same as `while (test != !lengthTest)` which seems wrong or overly complicated.

Comment: I would replace `choice = Integer.toString(input.nextInt()).charAt(0)` with `choice = input.nextInt()`

Comment: I would also print any exception as it might be important as to which one.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes you are correct. I made much more simple by removing `test` and now I am just doing `while (!lengthTest);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use String as an input paramenter, then any int value or char will be readed correctly without necessity to convert them:

```
      try {
           String choice = input.next();
           System.out.println(choice);
           switch (choice) {
           case "1":
               aOT.areaOfTriangle();
               break;
           case "2":
               hTDAH.hoursToDaysAndHours();
               break;
           case "3":
               cTF.celciusToFahrenheit();
           case "4":
               System.out.println("Code not implemented");
               break;
           case "e":
               repeat = false;
               break;
               default:
                   System.out.println("");
                   break;
        }
```

Comment: That did the trick! I also added `.toLowerCase();` to ignore Uppercase or Lower case

Answer (score 0):

You can't use int and chars at the same time, as you can only use one variable and a variable has to have a type, but:
If you cast a char or Character to int you get values. For example ((int) 'e') evaluates to 101 if I am not mistaken. (Try System.out.println((int) 'e'));
So in your case, you can switch over int values and detect for 1,2,3,4 and 101.
Your default should also throw an exception and you are fine.

Happy Coding

Comment: Lets say the user inputs 101 in the input, will that exit the code?

Comment: yes, then you have a problem :-) That's why in a real project you should do input checking an probably convert from types some semantic enum.

Comment: Yes I got it if fixed from the solution above. Changed it to String and it works

Comment: Yeah, that's the best solution here :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `char` representations of the digits 1-4:

```
char choice = input.next().charAt(0);
switch (choice) {
case '1':
    aOT.areaOfTriangle();
    break;
case '2':
    hTDAH.hoursToDaysAndHours();
    break;
case '3':
    cTF.celciusToFahrenheit();
case '4':
    System.out.println("Code not implemented");
    break;
case 'e':
    repeat = false;
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("");
    break;
}
```

Comment: The     `char choice = input.nextInt().charAt(0);`   didnt work it gave me  `Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the primitive type int`

Comment: @Nuggethed2003 meant to use `next()`, not `nextInt()`, sorry. Edited and fixed.